# Return joined data as flat array vs sub relation in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have one to many relationship in (recursive in my case)

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $selectable = [
        'id', 'category', 'parent_category'
    ];


    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

I want to return a items with their children. What I'm doing is this:

```
$data = Category::with('children')->get();
```

But it returns array of a collection of items. It's very fine for listing, but not for tabular view such as grid.
I basically want to return something like this (a flat array):

```
id   | category   | child_category
------------------------------------
1    | cat1       | subcat1
------------------------------------
1    | cat1       | subcat2
------------------------------------
1    | cat1       | subcat3
------------------------------------
2    | cat2       | subcat4
```

I know I can use a custom query builder, but I am trying to use Eloquent for a specific reason.

I also tried passing the column name to the relation (thinking this might get me closer to the solution) like this:

```
$data = Category::with('children: category')->get();
```

But it even give me an error:

`Unknown column ' category'`

I tried `toArray()` and `flatten()` but they didn't work (or maybe I didn't use them the proper way). Any help here?

Comment: When the Category model has the `category` field, it should work with `Category::with('children:category')` (without the space!).

Comment: I didn't know that space can affect. Thank you. Yet still how can I make my output two dimensional rather than multilevel array?